# How to convert MAC address to a link-local IPV6 address in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to convert a MAC address to a link-local IPV6 address using TCL. I have a code snippet that works well for all integer based MAC address but not for hex based like the ones, especially those that start with an non-numeral character. My current code:

```
set newmac AC:DE:48:1D:27:6D

lassign $newmac __o1 __o2 __o3 __o4 __o5 __o6

set __o1 [expr $__o1 ^ 0x02]  ;# universal bit flip

set __ip fe80::${__o1}${__o2}:${__o3}ff:fe${__o4}:${__o5}${__o6}
```

The bit flipping/inverting part does not work for this address, as I think the `expr` always expects a integer, although the same code works fine for other addresses like example - `55:12:34:26:21:97`

Can anybody suggest me a way to improve this code that works for all cases?

Answer (score 1):

First, the lassign as you have it will not work.
I have included the original lassign in the code below so you can see what happens.  You would have wanted:

```
lassign [split $newmac :] __o1 __o2 __o3 __o4 __o5 __o6
```

to achieve what you wanted.  You are completely correct that `expr` expects
integers.  Use the [scan](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.htm) command to scan the hex values from your string.
and then use [format](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) to convert back to hex.

```
set newmac AC:DE:48:1D:27:6D
lassign $newmac __o1 __o2 __o3 __o4 __o5 __o6
puts "$__o1 - $__o2 - $__o3 - $__o4 - $__o5 - $__o6"
scan $newmac {%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x} __o1 __o2 __o3 __o4 __o5 __o6
puts "$__o1 $__o2 $__o3 $__o4 $__o5 $__o6"
set __o1 [expr $__o1 ^ 0x02] ;# universal bit flip
set __ip [format {fe80::%02x%02x:%02xff:fe%02x:%02x%02x} \
    $__o1 $__o2 $__o3 $__o4 $__o5 $__o6]
puts "$__ip"
```

Output:

```
AC:DE:48:1D:27:6D -  -  -  -  - 
172 222 72 29 39 109
fe80::aede:48ff:fe1d:276d
```